# two tables with 100% width; in one line on wide screens; in two lines on narrow screens

Tags: html, css

I have two tables.

- On wide screen, tables should be in one line.
- On narrow screen, second table can wrap to the next line if necessary.

Which is easily done in the example below. However, I also want that in both cases, the tables fill 100% of the screen width.

- On wide screens, the two tables should together have 100% width.
- On narrow screen, in each line, each table should have 100% width.

https://jsfiddle.net/kkco4syr/

```
<table style="display: inline-table">
  <tr><th>A Lorem Ipsum</th><th>B Lorem Ipsum</th></tr>
  <tr><td>C Lorem Ipsum</td><td>D Lorem Ipsum</td></tr>
</table>
 <table style="display: inline-table">
  <tr><th>E Lorem Ipsum</th><th>F Lorem Ipsum</th></tr>
  <tr><td>G Lorem Ipsum</td><td>H Lorem Ipsum</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't you try bootstrap tables ?
[Bootstrap Table](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_bordered&stacked=h)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned, this is for a wikipedia. I am looking for a simple inline style css solution.